# What is the best way to do MyAjax error and success handling?

Tags: ajax

I'm doing an API call and if the response code is 200, I'm simply sending the name of the course as the output. If it's not 200, it will give the user a variety of errors based off the if checks. I need the name of the course to send to Google Analytics. I'm struggling to find a better way to isolate the name of the course and still be able to output the custom success/error messages and only send the GA action on success. Is there a better way to write this so I don't have to use javascript to see if the word error exists in the output variable? Just doesn't seem right, but I'm learning as I go so I don't know!

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_canvas_enroll', 'canvas_enroll' );
function canvas_enroll() {
global $current_canvas_user;
get_canvas_user();
get_currentuserinfo();

$su_course_codes = array(
    '43Dg21' => '10',
    );

if (!empty($current_canvas_user['suEmail'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['enrollmentCode']) && array_key_exists($_POST['enrollmentCode'], $su_course_codes)) {

        $course = canvas_api_req('url,'', 'GET', 'admin');
        $course_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $course );
        $course_decode = json_decode($course_body);
        $course_array = (array) $course_decode; 

        $response = canvas_api_req('url', array(), 'POST', 'access');

        $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );

        if ($response_code === 200) {
            $output = $course_array['name'];
        } else {
            $output = "<i class='fa fa-times-circle error'></i> There was a problem with your request. Please verify you are using the code you received in the enrollment email.";
        }
    } else {
            $output = "<i class='fa fa-times-circle error'></i> You have not entered a valid enrollment code.";
        }
} else {
    $output = "<i class='fa fa-times-circle error'></i> You must be logged in.";
}

exit( $output );    
}
```

My Javascript:

```
jQuery('#su-courses-sec').click(function() {

var enrollment_code = jQuery(".su-enroll-code").val();

var data = {
    action: 'canvas_enroll',
    enrollmentCode: enrollment_code
};

jQuery.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(output) {

    if (output.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") >= 0) {
    jQuery(".su-enter-enroll-code li").first().fadeOut(300, function() {
        jQuery(this).html(output).fadeIn(800);
    });
    } else {
    jQuery(".su-enter-enroll-code li").first().fadeOut(300, function() {
        jQuery(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o success'></i> Your enrollment in <b>" + output + "</b> was successful. <a href='#'>Start learning.</a>").fadeIn(800);
    });
    jQuery(".su-enroll-code").val('');

    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'Enrollments',
      eventAction: 'Addition',
      eventLabel: output
    });
    }    

});    

});
```

Comment: have a look at [`wp_send_json()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json).